# align navigation to the right in table

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with aligning my nav content to the right. I want my navigation text to be aligned to the right in the table. but it won't move.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<table width="159">
    <ul><img class="nav_img1" src="site/img/bullet.gif"><a class="nav_names"href="#">Strona główna</a></ul>
    <img class="nav_img2" src="site/img/nav_underline.gif">
    <ul><img class="nav_img1" src="site/img/bullet.gif"><a class="nav_names"href="#">Nasze działania</a></ul>
    <img class="nav_img2" src="site/img/nav_underline.gif">
    <ul><img class="nav_img1" src="site/img/bullet.gif"><a class="nav_names"href="#">Europolis</a></ul>
    <img class="nav_img2" src="site/img/nav_underline.gif">
    <ul><img class="nav_img1" src="site/img/bullet.gif"><a class="nav_names"href="#">Biesiady samorządowe</a></ul>
    <img class="nav_img2" src="site/img/nav_underline.gif">
    <ul><img class="nav_img1" src="site/img/bullet.gif"><a class="nav_names"href="#">Poezja. S.Stalmach</a></ul>
    <img class="nav_img2" src="site/img/nav_underline.gif">
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav_names{
    position: relative;
    color: #6283a9;

    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    /*font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    color: rgb(98, 131, 165);
    text-decoration: underline;*/

}
```

Comment: Your HTML is very invalid.

Comment: [see table example](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/tables.php) & [list items](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/ordered-unordered-definition-lists)

Comment: Confused as to why you have a table with no rows or cells. Either have a div with a list or have a table. You can't mix and match like that (not to say you can't in other ways but this makes no sense)

Answer (score 0):

In general this is how you align text to the right

```
#wrapper{
    text-align:right
}
```

In your case...yeah, your code is not formatted at all. You cannot use `<ul>` for links , inside of `<ul>` you need `<li>`, I guess thats what you wanted. Also you dont need table and you should never use tables for navigation links, only lists. This is due to accessibility issues and it is very important!

So do your menu like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul width="159">
    <li><img class="nav_img1" src="site/img/bullet.gif"><a class="nav_names"href="#">Strona główna</a></li>
...
...

  </ul>
</div>
```